# Horizontal Navigation Bar won't be as long as page

Tags: html, css

My horizontal nav bar won't take up the whole screen and I'm not sure how to get it to do that. **[Here's what it looks like.](https://gyazo.com/172470aaf4199b94af0af959fd6d102a)** Also, once it's done that, I want the image to be on top of the nav bar, instead of above it. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: aqua;
    float: right;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

img#sushi {}

nav ul {

}
```

```html
<a href=""><img src="../_images/imgres.jpg" id="Sushi" width="50" height="50" alt="Sushi"></a>
    <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `li`elements are floated, you have to add `overflow: auto;` to the `ul`  so that it will wrap the floated `li` s (otherwise it will have 0px height and therefore not be visible). Also, you have to apply the background color to the `ul`:

```css
nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: aqua;
  float: right;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

img#sushi {}

nav ul {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<a href=""><img src="../_images/imgres.jpg" id="Sushi" width="50" height="50" alt="Sushi"></a>
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

P.S.: The image link in your question leads to a page that shows nothing...

Comment: I placed his code into snippet but still pending for peer review.

Comment: That causes there to be a scroll bar, though.

Comment: Plus, the picture of sushi still isn't on top.

Comment: okay, change `overflow` to `hidden` instead of `auto` (see edited snippet). And ask one question at a time (your image isn't even included in your code, so what do you imagine people can do for you?)

Comment: concerning the image: Delete the `img` tag and define the image as a `background-image` for the `nav`element

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your nav element:

```
<nav id='header' role="navigation">
```

Then add this to your css:

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 150px; //Whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

try moving float: right from nav li to nav  like below

change nav li to this..

```
nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

and add nav like this..

```
nav {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also if you are not sure about element blocks etc you can always add this to your css and test:

```
* {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

and example you can see here, https://jsfiddle.net/

**for your problem the solutions are the following:**

1st: take out `display: inline-block;` from `nav li` and move to `nav a`

2nd: move img to ul

3rd: background color for ul should be aqua

```css
/*CSS Reset*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: aqua;
    float: right;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}

img#sushi {}

nav ul {
 background: aqua;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale:1.0">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <a href=""><img src="../_images/imgres.jpg" id="Sushi" width="50" height="50" alt="Sushi"></a>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```